# Linux 5.10 E5-2666 V3 hyperthreading not detected

Tags: linux, hyperthreading

Per the title, I have a Supermicro X10-DRLi based machine with 2x E5-2666 V3 (the Amazon OEM CPUs) in it.
Secure Boot, FWIW, is disabled.

Linux 5.10 (debian 11 stock kernel, amd64) tells me via the `/sys/devices/system/cpu/smt/control` interface that SMT is 'notsupported'. According to Intel, it should be.

Where is the issue and how can I change it? Is it possible that the 'unusual' CPU is not being identified as HT capable? The HT flag is present in `dmidecode` and `/proc/cpuinfo` . And yes, HT is enabled in the BIOS, which is the latest for the MB.

Comment: so, you only have 20 CPU's in /proc/cpuinfo? i.e. 10 for each socket?

Comment: Exactly. And lscpu gives me one thread per core.